# How to transpose array of strings in Julia?

Tags: julia

It works with numbers but not with strings.

The `[1 2]'` works but the `["a" "b"]'` doesn't.

Why? And how to do that?

Comment: Try the ˋpermutedimsˋ function.

Comment: Is it possible that what you need is `vec(["a" "b"])`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Why?**

`["a" "b"]'` does not work because the `'` operator actually computes the (lazy) adjoint of your matrix. Note that, as stated in the documentation, [`adjoint`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#Base.adjoint) is recursive:

> **Base.adjoint** — *Function*
>
> `adjoint(A)`
>
> Lazy adjoint (conjugate transposition) (also postfix `'`). Note that `adjoint` is applied recursively to elements.
>
> This operation is intended for linear algebra usage - for general data manipulation see permutedims.

What happens in the case of `[1 2]` is that `adjoint` does not only flip elements across the diagonal; it also recursively calls itself on each element to conjugate it. Since conjugation is not defined for strings, this fails in the case of `["a" "b"]`.

**How?**

As suggested by the documentation, use [`permutedims`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.permutedims) for general data manipulation:

```
julia> permutedims(["a" "b"])
2×1 Array{String,2}:
 "a"
 "b"
```

Answer (score 6):

Transposing is normally for linear algebra operations but in your case the easiest thing is just to drop the dimension:

```
julia> a = ["a" "b"]
1×2 Array{String,2}:
 "a"  "b"

julia> a[:]
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "a"
 "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string matrix is created by a literal, the easiest way is to create a vector immediately instead of a matrix.

```
["a", "b"]
```