# Transpose of dataframe with an index that has tuples in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I understand Julia DataFrames do not have a .set_index() function and you need to just use a column instead. However, is there any way to transpose a dataframe or go from dataframe -> matrix -> transpose and preserve a column that consists of a tuple, or do column names definitionally have to be strings?

I have some python code from an original PuLP model which is as follows:

```
edgedata = df_edges
edgedata['orig_dest'] = list(zip(edgedata['orig_node_id'], edgedata['dest_node_id']))
edgedata = edgedata.set_index(['orig_dest'])
edgedata = edgedata[['transp_cost_tot_usd', 'transm_cost_usd_GJ', 'cap_Mt', 'conversion_eff']]
edgedata  = edgedata.T.to_dict('list')
(transp_cost_tot_usd, transm_cost_usd_GJ, cap_Mt, conversion_eff) = splitDict(edgedata)
```

I have worked this in Julia as follows:

```
edgedata = df_edges
edgedata[:,"orig_dest"] = collect(zip(edgedata[:,"orig_node_id"],edgedata[:,"dest_node_id"])) 
edgedata = edgedata[:,["orig_dest","transp_cost_tot_usd","transm_cost_usd_GJ","cap_Mt","conversion_eff"]]
edgedata_matrix = Matrix(edgedata)
```

The next line fails however:

```
edgedata_transpose = transpose(edgedata_matrix)
```

The error is:

MethodError: no method matching transpose(::Tuple{String15, String15})

The problem I am having here is there is an index in the original python dataframe that has two tuples and I am trying to transpose that and keep column names that are two tuples. Is there any way to do this in Julia or does DataFrames.jl not accept column names with tuple objects?

Comment: See also [How to transpose array of strings in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60443127)

Answer (score 3):

You want `permutedims`.

```
help?> transpose
search: transpose transpose! Transpose ConvTranspose copy_transpose! batched_transpose

  transpose(A)

  Lazy transpose. Mutating the returned object should appropriately mutate A. Often, but not
  always, yields Transpose(A), where Transpose is a lazy transpose wrapper. Note that this
  operation is recursive.

  This operation is intended for linear algebra usage - for general data manipulation see
  permutedims, which is non-recursive.

[...]

julia> [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
3-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 2)
 (3, 4)
 (5, 6)

julia> permutedims(ans)
1×3 Matrix{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 2)  (3, 4)  (5, 6)
```

Comment: I came here to post this! (side note: what a strange name, for something which has nothing to do with permutations)

Comment: It absolutely has something to do with permutations, e.g. `permutedims(rand(10,20,30), (3,1,2)) |> size` gives `(30, 10, 20)`. The one-arg method is for matrices because there's only one permutation of two items. And the one-arg method for vectors is... because so many people think of vectors as being almost 1-column matrices?

Comment: by "there's only one permutation of two items", do you mean there's only one other permutation, other than the current one? I.e. the permutations of A and B are B, A and A, B

Comment: Sure, something like "one non-trivial permutation" would have been better.